# Searching for a page with a Very Unique title, doesnt find that intended page... Why?

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search, search, title

a question about appearing in search results in google:

A page of mine has this extremely unique page title:

***Ein gutes Logo passt wie ein Handschuh auf Ihre Marke in die Hände***

Now, when I search the phrase:

`Ein gutes Logo passt wie ein Handschuh auf Ihre Marke in die Hände`

Then all kinds of other irrelevant pages show up having only 1 or at best two words from my unqie title appearing, although I have searched for the entire phrase! And when I search the phrase in between quotes:

`"Ein gutes Logo passt wie ein Handschuh auf Ihre Marke in die Hände"`

Then it finds 1 result, which is my page.

What is going on? Why doesn't show the unique result without the quotes?

Thanks: your ideas and suggestions are welcome and much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me say I'm surprised by the results as that phrase is so unique that I would think an exact match would trump everything but that clearly is not the case. Then again, without quotes it is assumed you are not necessarily looking for an exact match  and it's very possible other important words or phrases in that original text may simply grab precedence.

Having said that, the text itself is not the only ranking factor. This is a perfect example of that. The anchor text of incoming links to those other pages, content on those pages, PR of those pages, etc, all add up to be stronger then the exact match of the text. If you're ranked well, just not ahead of those pages, it may not take much to get you to outrank them. Possibly just a few links with that anchor might do it.